# Performing an Excel-like "vlookup" method in Pyspark

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm new to Pyspark I would like some help with this. I have a Pyspark dataframe `df1` like the one below:

```
df1 =
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|     ID_Machine      |  Event_Duration  |     Timestamp    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         34       |        213       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         97       |        572       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         78       |        872       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         83       |        345       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         14       |        718       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         115      |        884       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

From it, I have to perform a `groupBy` with an aggregate method:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df1.groupBy("ID_Machine").agg(F.max("Event_duration").alias("Max_Event_Duration")
```

Thus obtaining:

```
df2 = 
|---------------------|---------------------------|
|      ID_Machine     |     Max_Event_Duration    |
|---------------------|---------------------------|
|           1         |             97            |
|---------------------|---------------------------|
|           2         |             115           |
|---------------------|---------------------------|
```

So far, so good. However, now I would like to perform some sort of fuction like `vlookup` in Excel, where I retrieve the `Timestamp` value in `df1` corresponding to the `Max_Event_Duration` in `df2`, obtaining something like the following:

```
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|     ID_Machine      |  Max_Event_Duration |     Timestamp    |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |          97         |        572       |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |          115        |        884       |
|---------------------|---------------------|------------------|
```

Does anybody know how to create this third dataframe or how to modify the code which creates `df2` in order to include the respective `Timestamp` value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to first create a dataframe with the max event named same as in the OG dataframe

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_max = df1.groupBy("ID_Machine").agg(F.max("Event_Duration").alias("Event_Duration"))
df_max.show()
```

which would give you `df`:

```
+----------+--------------+
|ID_Machine|Event_Duration|
+----------+--------------+
|         1|            97|
|         2|           115|
+----------+--------------+
```

Then join the dataframe by the two similar named columns and then rename the event duration

```py
df_combined = df_max.join(df1, ["ID_Machine", "Event_Duration"]).withColumnRenamed("Event_Duration", "Max_Event_Duration")
df_combined.show()
```

which would give you:

```
+----------+------------------+---------+
|ID_Machine|Max_Event_Duration|Timestamp|
+----------+------------------+---------+
|         2|               115|      884|
|         1|                97|      572|
+----------+------------------+---------+
```

Comment: This is less efficient than my answer below - a join is needed here but my answer does not need a join

Comment: I ran some tests to both and timed them. There is not significant difference between the implementations in execution time, it was a difference of 0.02 seconds on average with the method I used being a little faster. @mck

Comment: if you test it on this tiny dataset it probably won't make a difference, but if you work on a dataframe with millions of rows my method is definitely faster

Comment: Okay, can you shed a light when not to use join and when to use it? This information seems to really be under the rock

Comment: Don't use joins if you can avoid it. Joins are almost always slower than methods without joins.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a new column of `max_event_duration` and filter the columns where `event_duration = max_event_duration`

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df1.select('*', F.max("Event_duration").over(Window.partitionBy("ID_Machine")).alias("Max_Event_Duration")) \
         .filter("Event_duration = Max_Event_Duration") \
         .drop("Max_Event_Duration")
```